# How to use material ui props with media queries

Tags: material-ui

I just need to know that how to use material ui props with media queries? As an example, let's say I have a typography component and I assigned variant prop to h1 and then I need variant prop to change h5 at the screen size less than 600px.

How to do that?

I know that in material ui v5 has style hook and I have used media queries inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useTheme` and `useMediaQuery` like below:

```
function Test() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));
  return (
    <Typography variant={matches ? "h1" : "h5"}>
      my text ...
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Or simply use `useMediaQuery`:

```
function Test() {
  const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');
  return (
    <Typography variant={matches ? "h1" : "h5"}>
      my text ...
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you @mahooresorkh.Is there any alternative way to solve this problem using  styled hook inmaterial v5?As a example I have attached a link with here.[link](https://codepen.io/lakruwanpathirage/pen/rNJXEOZ).In there I have used styled hook with media query.

Comment: As far as I know after compilation, `styled` utility ultimately leads to modification and overriding elements properties in CSS. But what you mentioned in the text of the question, is the change in DOM structure. That is, the `h1` tag is removed when the page width is less than `600px` and the `h5` is inserted. Naturally, such a thing should be done by JavaScript (through react and its hooks).

Comment: Thank you @mahooresorkh.This makes much sense. thank you!